# How to solve install TestNG plug-in for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium, testng

I am trying to install TestNg  from (http://beust.com/eclipse) this site  and it gives:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /eclipse/ on this server.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And how exactly are you trying to install it?

Comment: it's server side issue. Please try again later.

Comment: @venu are you trying this from eclipse?

Comment: yes.., i am trying to install in eclipse Kepler.